# How to solve this macro error that only shows up when running in IIS?

Tags: .net, database, macros

I have developed a .NET application that access to an Access database. That Access database has some macros that generate PDF files using the info from the database. The application works perfect in the development environment (Visual Studio 2010) but when I publish it in IIS and run it the following error shows up:

*The '|1' macro action cannot run with the specified '|2' argument either when in disabled mode or when called from an embedded macro.*

I'd like to mention that the database belongs to a trusted location and has macros enabled. In fact it's the same that I call from the development environment. Anything would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that your server side installation has all the Office components installed so that it can access the Access database. If not, you probably need to install Access/Office or at least some drivers on your server. I will reserve any opinions on the topic of whether this is a good idea or not.

I had this issue running macros in an Access database under SSIS, inside a Script Task.

- The Task would run on my desktop under the development environment
- it would run on the server under the development environment
- it would run on the server as a scheduled job executed while remoted onto the server
- it would run on the server as a scheduled job started remotely but only while I had an open remote desktop onto the server

I eventually went through all the entries in the Registry on the server under HKEY_USERS and looked for Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Security.

There were a number of entries that did not have an entry for VBAWarnings and in those instances I created a DWORD VBAWarnings and set it to 1. This seemed to solve the problem for me.

My conclusion is that Access runs under a slightly different arrangement when it is executed through a scheduled task.

I hope this is actually the same problem and this solves your issue too.